# how to handle outliers for clustering algorithms?

Tags: clustering, outlier

I am wondering what's the best way to handle outliers when using non-supervised clustering algorithms?

Answer (score 4):

If you have outliers, the best way is to **use a clustering algorithm that can handle them**.

For example DBSCAN clustering is robust against outliers when you choose minpts large enough. Don't use k-means: the squared error approach is sensitive to outliers. But there are variants such as k-means-- for handling outliers.

Comment: Thanks! So does DBSCAN make each outlier a separated cluster? Then we can remove clusters with very small sizes. Or what is the mechanism DBSCAN uses to identify the outliers?

Comment: It labels them as "noise", not as clusters at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can perform standardization of your data using Standard Scaler before applying clustering techniques or you can use k-mediod clustering algorithm. You can also use z-score analysis to remove your outliers.

Comment: what do you mean 'remove'?